# Can't connect to Remote Server in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

This only happens on occasion, then will fix itself at some point so I want to know if there's ways to prevent something like this or at least find the reason.

I have multiple connections to my Local, Dev, Staging, and Prod servers - the latter 3 being hosted on AWS. My Local connection works fine, but if I try to open my hosted connections, I sometimes get the following error:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'myuser' to the MySQL server
> at 'myhostserver': Unable to connect to localhost.

Why is it trying to connect to localhost here? And localhost is working so I'm not sure wha the issue is. I have ensured the account credentials are correct and the servers are up because other people are querying them - both in development and production environments.